# Can't pull friends' photos, even though permission is correct

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying to pull the photos a particular friend is tagged in. So I created an access token with the `user_photos` and `friends_photos` permissions.

1. I can run a query to get photos I am tagged in:

   `SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()`
2. I can refer to myself using me() or by user_id:

   `SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=1102318`

But when I ask for photos a friend is tagged in, I get empty set:

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=1102054
```

--> []

What's odd is that I can pull **all** `photo_tags` of **all** friends, using the following (massive) query:

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

--> works(!), returns the first 1400 or so. So it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

I can also get photos of a single user selected from the previous table

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() LIMIT 1)
```

--> also works

But indexing the table fails

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)
```

--> []

I was wondering if anyone else has seen anything like this behavior before. I filed a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/135294859957800?browse=search_50c2c6322810e2d66872956), I'll report back if I hear anything.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer but it doesn't answer the question as the title indicated that "permissions were correct". Specifically the fact that `SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() LIMIT 1)` works indicates that the user hasn't disallowed sharing.

Answer (score 2):

What facebook doesn't openly tell you, is that users can decide what kind of data to make available to apps that OTHER facebook users use (check out "Apps others use" section [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view)). So if user 1102054 in your example decided to disallow his photos to be accessed by apps used by other people, then a query such as

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=1102054
```

will fail.

However, if user 1102054 in your example AND someone else that allows apps to access photos is tagged in a particular picture, then you can still access that picture through a query by doing:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=1102054
             AND pid in (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=<other user id here>)
```

Careful, though. Switching the above two user ids as so will still return an empty data set:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=<other user id here>
             AND pid in (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=1102054)
```